# Как получить значение тега span

Tags: span

Кусочек кода:

```html
<div class="test">
<span>тест</span></div>
```

Получить класс не проблема

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('test');
```

Подскажите, как получить span (тест) этого класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.test > span').innerHTML);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].children[0].innerHTML);
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <span>тест</span>
</div>
```

Comment: А если на странице несколько классов test, как получить все span этих классов?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` @Влад, либо же пройтись по всех элементах (можно увидеть `[0]` в конце каждой выборки)